# How do I call a function from another class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and have some problems with moving my logic outside the main file. Can someone tell me how to refer to the Player object created in the main file?

**Here is the main file, from which I want to call the Player::move() method**

**EDIT** Now the compiler complains that I'm calling the move() method on a NULL  object.

```
      class MainViewState extends State<MainView> {
  GlobalKey<PlayerState> playerKey;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    playerKey = GlobalKey<PlayerState>();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap:playerKey.currentState.move, // -  here I want to call my move function
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("image/background.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        new Player(key: playerKey),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

**And here is the file with the move() method, which should change the alignment of my image**

```
    class Player extends StatefulWidget {
  
  Player({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  PlayerState createState() => PlayerState();
}

class PlayerState extends State<Player> {
  double ypos = 0;
  void move() // method I want to call
  {
   setState(() {
    ypos -= 0.1;
    print(ypos);
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
        alignment: Alignment(0, ypos),
        child: Image.asset(
          "image/test.png",
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          height: 60,
          width: 60,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as picture.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about your question with code?

Comment: What is the actual error message you are getting? If `playerkey.currentState.move` gives a null pointer exception, that means `playerkey.currentState` is `null`. Did you set it?

Comment: This is the error . The getter 'move' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: move. I guess the problem is, that the move() method is called before a Player object is created, but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Import the file  containing the class in the main file then create an object for the class containing the method and call the method on the object. In case of static method use the class name instead of object  reference.

MyClass myClassObject = MyClass(....);
myClassObject.myMethod();

MyClass.myMethod(); //for static methods

Comment: I implemented it according to your advice, but there are still some issues, shown in the edited post.

Comment: When using widgets and state classes you should have to do  certain changes.. 1.call the Player() constructor  with a global key object .. Player(globalKey) in your widget build method 2. Pass the key in Player class to the stateful widget.. 3. While calling move.. use globalKey.currentState.move();   the key genedally works like an id.

Comment: I hope that I understood you correctly. Unfortunately another error occured (edited post)

Comment: @AndrzejSzafarczyk move the initialization  of playerKey into the initState override method;


void initState(){
  playerKey = GlobalKey<PlayerState>();
  super.initState();
}

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Check with the hashcode of your playerstate and does that match with that of the currentstate in key... also check for nulls before calling the method. Playerkey.currentstate?.move();

Answer (score 0):

So thank's to @daringdk I made it work. Overwriting the initstate method and passing the globalKey to the Stateful object was the solution.

**The main file **

```
   void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MainView()));

class MainView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MainViewState createState() => MainViewState();
}

class MainViewState extends State<MainView> {
  GlobalKey<PlayerState> playerKey;

  @override
  void initState() {
    playerKey = GlobalKey<PlayerState>();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        playerKey.currentState.move(); // - My mistake was here that I thought that I'm supposed to return a function pointer here. <FACEPALM> . The currlybraces made it.
      },
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("image/background.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        new Player(key: playerKey),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

**The player file**

```
   class Player extends StatefulWidget {
  Player({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  PlayerState createState() => PlayerState();
}

class PlayerState extends State<Player> {
  double ypos = 0;
  void move() // method I want to call
  {
    setState(() {
      ypos -= 0.1;
      print(ypos);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
        alignment: Alignment(0, ypos),
        child: Image.asset(
          "image/test.png",
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          height: 60,
          width: 60,
        ));
  }
}
```